# Sort pics in folder

Tags: windows, powershell, directory

I have a folder with 34K pics, I need to sort of pics created between 12 o'clock and 15 o'clock.

Here is my code:

```
Get-ChildItem C:/kaust *.jpg | Where-Object {
    $_.CreationTime.Hour -gt 12 -and $_.CreationTime.Hour -lt 15
} | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\pildid"
```

I tried it with txt files and it worked, but with jpg it doesn't do anything.

Comment: By "sort" you mean "copy to a different folder"? Because that's what your code would do. And from what I can see that should work. Does `Get-ChildItem` return any JPEG files in the first place? Do any of those have creation timestamps between 12:00 and 15:59?

Comment: Hi Urmet and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think @AnsgarWiechers is right about checking the CreationTime to see if there are indeed pictures between 12:00 and 15:00 in there. But maybe.. it would be better to use the `LastWriteTime` for each jpg file because if you have copied them of a digital camera for instance first to the `C:\kaust` folder, the creation times for all of these pics will become the date and time of when you copied them. The `LastWriteTime` is the time the pictures were actually taken.

Comment: `$_.CreationTime.Hour -gt 12` means 13 o'clock, better usee `-ge 12`

Comment: Does the day of creation matter? Should files created 10 days ago between 12:00  and 15:00 be included?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `C:/kaust` to `C:\kaust` in your code. The Windows filesystem uses backslashes instead of slashes as delimiting characters in file paths. Also, check out [this helpful article on finding metadata in images.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/)

Thanks,
Gabe